# How can I define a BigInt primary key with Rails 2.1 and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, biginteger

Since Rails 2.1, if you define a new column in a migration with the type set to :integer and the :limit set to 5 or more, the column actually created in your MySQL database will be of type BigInt.  That's perfect.

But I cannot figure out how to create a table with a BigInt primary key.

Any clues?

Comment: Defining the column with :limit more than 5 seems not to work in my Rails 2.3.9 app. Any ideas where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled upon [this plugin](http://svn.northpub.com/plugins/mysql_bigint/README): it seems to answer this very question.

Answer (score 1):

This works in rails 3 not sure if it would work in rails 2.

Throughout my app I needed my primary keys to be bigint unsigned.
What I ended up doing was putting in my config/environment.rb

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] =
  "BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY".freeze
```

This lets rails automatically create id's as BigInts.
When I do a refrence from another table I do the following

```
t.column :product_id, 'BIGINT UNSIGNED'
```